# how to get real time report with google report API

Tags: google-api

I'm trying to create a real-time app to capture google meet activity report. I can retrieve the activity report by getting request from *https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/email/applications/meet*. But I found that the event is not real-time and I only can get latest refresh in an amount of time(5 to 8 minutes) after event happened. I tried to watch the meet resource as well but got notification of activity in at least 10 minutes.  Is there any way to get the activity event report or notice once it happen(for example, I can get event of *call_end* once a google meet is end)?